# How to handle accessibilty in fabric js like setting the pointer in desired position using keyboard events?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas, accessibility, fabricjs

I want to handle accessibility in fabric js. I have this code for pencil tool and I want to handle this tool functionality using keyboard events too.

```
import { fabric } from 'fabric';

class Pencil {
    constructor(canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
        this.activate();
        this.initialiseEvents();
    }

    initialiseEvents = () => {
        
    }

    activate = () => {
        this.canvas.freeDrawingBrush = new fabric.PencilBrush(this.canvas);
        this.canvas.isDrawingMode = true;
        document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
            if (event.key === ' ' && event.shiftKey) {
                console.log('inside canvas');
            }
        });
    }

    deactivate = () => {
        this.canvas.isDrawingMode = false;
    }
}

export default Pencil;
```

This code works fine when used with mouse.
I have used document.addEventListener to read keyboard events and it works fine. I want to now set the position of the pointer in canvas to the top-leftmost corner to start with and then want to be able to draw using the pencilBrush such as when I press arrowLeft then the brush should move to left and so on. I'm not able to find how to do that? How to set the pointer position? How to make the pencilBrush work using arrow keys? Please provide some insights.